# Erro "Notice: Undefined index:"

Tags: php

Olá!
    Estou recebendo esta mensagem ao tentar exibir a página.

*Notice: Undefined index: IdEntregador in C:\wamp64\www\solus\resumo_dia.php on line 378*

Na linha 378 tenho a seguinte estrutura.

```
375- $sqlEntregasRetornos_res = $conn->prepare($sqlEntregasRetornos);
376- $sqlEntregasRetornos_res->execute();        
377- $lstEntregasRet = $sqlEntregasRetornos_res>fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
378- $teste = $lstEntregasRet["IdEntregador"];                      
379- var_dump($lstEntregasRet);

// Na linha 378 também tentei extrair da seguinte forma     
   $lstEntregasRet["IdEntregador"];
```

> Ao exibir o conteúdo da variável ele está exibindo corretamente as informações. 
>   Conforme abaixo:

```
array (size=8)
  0 => 
    array (size=3)
      'IdEntregador' => string '4' (length=1)
      'QtdeRetorno' => string '4' (length=1)
      'Descricao' => string 'RETORNO' (length=7)
  1 => 
    array (size=3)
      'IdEntregador' => string '20' (length=2)
      'QtdeRetorno' => string '1' (length=1)
      'Descricao' => string 'RETORNO' (length=7)
```

A variável $teste retorna null
C:\wamp64\www\solus\resumo_dia.php:381:null

Sinceramente, não sei o que posso estar fazendo de errado, tenho outras 4 estruturas que estão funcionando perfeitamente, já conferi todas informações e não sei o que está errado.
Tive outra situação similar a essa, porém resolvi em 2 min, o problema estava na estrutura do foreach, o que não é o caso agora.

Comment: Na linha 377 o correto é $sqlEntregasRetornos_res->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)

Comment: Estava faltando um '-' antes do '>'

Comment: Creio que não seja esse o problema, pois se notar, eu inseri o '-> ' nesse caso ele um retornaria um 'Error' ao invés do valor existente na variável.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No seu dump está mostrado claramente qual é o problema. É que lstEntregasRet está recebendo TODAS as linhas da consulta.

Você tem q fazer um foreach de lstEntregasRet e pegar cada subarray,

```
foreach ($lstEntregasRet as $linha)
{
    $IdEntregador = $linha['IdEntregador'];
    ...
}
```

Comment: Farei isso!
Na minha ignorância pensei que o FETCH_ASSOC se comportasse como um FETCH_OBJ exibindo a informaçao de dentro da variável.
Agradeço muito pela atenção.